# UITabBarController's first view of type UINavigationController not acting quite right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So I've got a UITabBarController as a view in my app, the first tab of which is a UINavigationController. I have a button inside this view that pushes another, custom view onto the stack:

```
myViewController *vc = [[myViewController alloc] init];
[self pushViewController:myOtherView animated:YES];
```

The class `myViewController` has things that are supposed to happen inside of both `-viewDidLoad` and `-viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`, but if I hit my button right after the UITabBarController view appears, neither of those methods seem to be called. And even stranger, when I hit "Back", the view does not animate away, but rather the view underneath it in the stack just pops back into place.

However, if I go to another tab in the tab bar, then go back to the first tab, then hit my button again, my custom view controller animates in, `-viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` is called, and it animates out of view upon hitting "Back" like it should. Unfortunately, `-viewDidLoad` is never called.

I'm really trying to get away from using Interface Builder for everything; I want to create this view controller purely programatically, but these weird issues aren't helping. Can anyone think of a reason for this bizarre behavior?

Edit: Even if I create my view controller via IB, this behavior still occurs. What's the deal? Do I need to do something to the UITabBarController?

Edit #2: Here's how I want my views to bet set up:

- UITabBarControler

  - Tab 1: UINavigationController

    - UIViewController to be pushed onto the stack

      - UIViewController to be pushed onto the stack
      - etc (possibly more UIViewControllers)
  - Tab 2: UIViewController
  - Tab 3: UINavigation Controller

    - UIViewController to be pushed onto the stack

      - UIViewController to be pushed onto the stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what kind of object contains the code you posted but, if it's handling a button action, it's probably a custom view controller that's managed by your navigation controller.  If that's true, then you'd want `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myOtherView animated:YES];`.

(If `self` is some other kind of object or `self.navigationController` is nil, then you would need to add some more details about your current view controller structure.)

Comment: Sorry about that. It's a subclass of UINavigationController.

Comment: Ah...that's probably part of the problem.  From the UINavigationController docs, "This class is not intended for subclassing."  Usually, you would create a standard UINavigationController along with the first "normal" view controller subclass (which would have the handler for your button) and put it in the tab.  Then, when you wanted a different "normal" controller, you'd create and push it.

Comment: Oh, interesting. So anything I think I should be doing inside of my UINavigationController subclass, I should really be doing inside of the rootViewController of a non-subclassed UINavigationController, huh?

Comment: That would get you into territory that's better understood.  :)  UINavigationController is really just a tool for managing a stack of your custom-built view controllers and providing a standard way of moving among them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your insight! I can't even remember why I wanted to subclass UINavigationController in the first place... Oh I guess I thought to access things like self.navigationItem inside of a controller, it had to extend UINavigationController? But I guess you get access to that by being virtue of a UINavigationController's root view, huh?

Comment: One more thing: It's possible to use a custom subclassed UINavigationBar with a regular UINavigationController, isn't it?

Comment: I **think** you only get the UINavigationBar that comes with the controller, but you can access it to customize it and the items it contains.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16673/discussion-between-hi-there-and-phillip-mills)